# GitHub: What happens to forks when a repo changes ownership?

Tags: git, github

If a repo changes ownership from owner/theRepo to newOwner/theRepo are its forks automatically updated to reference the new location of the moved repo? Or does anything need to be done manually?

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/about-repository-transfers/#whats-transferred-with-a-repository):

> **If the transferred repository has any forks**, then those forks will remain associated with the repository after the transfer is complete